# As the submitting author, is it OK to submit work first as the corresponding author, and change later on to reduce communication time?

Tags: paper-submission

The question looks a little complicated, but I think most of you has gone through this hassle many times so I am asking if there is a convenient way to do this.

The journal I am about to submit a small work is using the old and classic Editorial Manager system.

This work has two authors, Me(1st, submitting author), and my senior, the corresponding author.
This designation has been clearly stated in the title page and the manuscript also.

However in editorial manager system, you have to send the compiled pdf to the corresponding author for approval at the last minute. After you send it to the corresponding author, the submitted work disappears from the submitting author's account, and the work can only be viewed in the corresponding author's account after that point.This situation is very frustrating for  the submitting author who does the main job to check the manuscript status. I have to ask my senior author to check up on the manuscript status every time.

So my idea is, are there any of first authors who submit the work as a corresponding author at the early stage, to keep the submission with the first author, and change it to the real corresponding author at the later stages. Clearly, this is not a breach of authorship because the author designation is stated in the manuscript itself.

Comment: I'd also consider not checking the manuscript status so often.